# Catch Back (as Catch Again, to represent recurrence)

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

Is it correct to say *"Catch Back"* with the intention to express recurrence?
For example, assume I once felt joyful but then that feeling faded.
If *now* I'm somehow feeling happy again, could I say:

*"I'm **catching back** the spirit/vibe"* ?

Note that this is to represent - probably in a figurative sense - that I'm in possession of something I once had.

I've been searching for this one but couldn't find any useful information. I know that *'Back'* can be used as an adverb holding quite different meanings, still, I don't know if there's a *rule* that may limit its use as an adverb.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It kinda sorta works in the sense of "recovering" -- "I'm recovering the spirit".

Comment: I appreciate your comments. I came across "get back", and I figured it might have that same meaning I was looking for. Nevertheless, I wonder if "catch smth back" could have that same meaning, although I think I've never heard it.

Comment: I would replace it with *Recapture*, you have recaptured the spirit from the past.